# TFastDib and pixels

Tags: delphi

im trying to work with pixels , im using TFastDib for better results. But , i have a trouble with counting start image point.

Let me explain:

We have image 5x5 pixels.

1 Pixel , as i understand , should be in UPPER LEFT corner , but i have it in LOWER LEFT.

[image]

```
  FImg := TFastDib.Create;

  LoadJPGFile (FImg, CurrImgPath, false);

  Wave(FImg,5,5,15,15);

  FImg.Pixels24[19,19]:=tfPurple;
  FImg.Pixels[21,21]:=tfRed;
```

How do I fix this? Its impossible for my mind to start counting pixels from bottom.

Comment: There's nothing to fix. Count from the bottom up. What's so hard about that?

Comment: Its unusual, i cant get used to it... Its like a read line from the end

Comment: It is a common scenario to have the origo at bottom left. See also [`Device-Independent Bitmaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183562(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It's not unusual at all. Get used to it.

Comment: I can't see what the problem is here at all, other than OP not wanting to implement a common practice.

Comment: I find your comment that bottom up bitmaps is akin to reading from the right to be odd. Do you know that vast numbers of people habitually read and right right to left?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own TFastDIB, that builds on the existing one but reverses the Y-coordinate system like this:

```
TYPE
  TUpsideDownFastDIB    = CLASS(TFastDIB)
                          PROTECTED
                            PROCEDURE   SetPixel(X,Y : Cardinal ; C : TColor);
                            FUNCTION    GetPixel(X,Y : Cardinal) : TColor;
                          PUBLIC
                            PROPERTY    Pixels[X,Y : Cardinal] : TColor Read GetColor Write SetColor;
                          END;

PROCEDURE TUpsideDownFastDIB.SetPixel(X,Y : Cardinal ; C : TColor);
  BEGIN
    INHERITED Pixels[X,Height-Y]:=C
  END;

FUNCTION TUpsideDownFastDIB.GetPixel(X,Y : Cardinal) : TColor;
  BEGIN
    Result:=INHERITED Pixels[X,Height-Y]
  END;
```

Then instead of

```
FImg := TFastDib.Create;
```

you'd use

```
FImg := TUpsideDownFastDIB.Create;
```

(and remember to declare FImg as TUpsideDownFastDIB)

You'll need to implement a custom function for all routines that accepts a Y-coordinate in the same manner as above, that turns the coordinate system upside down and then calls on to the original implementation. I have shown you how to do this for the Pixels property - you'll have to do it yourself for the remaining properties and functions.

DISCLAIMER: I don't know TFastDIB, so I am unsure how to get the height of the bitmap. I have assumed that it has a property "Height" that returns the height of the underlying bitmap. If this is an incorrect assumption, you'll have to replace the use of Height in the methods you implement with the correct way to get at the underlying bitmap's height.